# How to get three dots for the breadcrumb when it is too long in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, breadcrumbs

**Problem**

Whenever I have a dynamic breadcrumb like:

```
Root > folder1 > folder2 > folder3 > Currentfolder
```

I should get the breadcrumb like,

```
Root > . . . > Current folder.
```

**Question**

When I click on three dots, I should get the full path.

I am trying to write this code in `Angularjs`.

Please anybody help me.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this (check the fiddle for the corresponding js):

```
<span ng-repeat="item in breadcrumbs">
    <a ng-show="!($middle &amp;&amp; shortened)">
      <span ng-show="!$first"> > </span>
      {{item}}
      <span ng-show="$first &amp;&amp; shortened"> > </span>
    </a>
    <a ng-show="$middle &amp;&amp; shortened" ng-click="toggleShortened()">.</a>    
</span>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/21036/

It is far for the most elegant approach, but I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve the same thing with pure CSS, if you like. Put the extra breadcrumbs inside a container that can receive focus (e.g. `<span class="extra-breadcrumbs" tabindex="0">`). The default style would be to hide everything inside this container and display the placeholder content. Something like:

```
.extra-breadcrumbs > * {
    display: none;
}

.extra-breadcrumbs:after {
    content: '. . .'
}
```

Then, when the container receives focus (through a click), you can display the hidden items and hide the placeholder:

```
.extra-breadcrumbs:focus > * {
    display: initial;
}

.extra-breadcrumbs:focus:after {
    display: none;
}
```